# How to convert int to char (not const char) for use with putChar();

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, type-conversion

I'm writing a QT Console Application to write out of an FTDI cable using the QSerialport library. (the FTDI cable is connected to a logic analyzer so I can debug the output)

I need to pass `int x = 255;` to the line `myserial->putChar();`

I tried to convert the int to a char using:

`int x = 255;
std::string s = std::to_string(x);
char const *myChar = s.c_str();
myserial->putChar(myChar);`

and received the error:

`cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char' with an lvalue of type 'const char*'`

However in this test starting with a char everything works perfectly:

`char myChar = 255;
myserial->putChar(myChar);`

Giving the correct result of `0xFF` on the logic analyzer.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: You will pass 255 as a code of symbol or not?

Answer (score 1):

Just do it:

```
int x = 255;
mySerial->putChar(x);
```

The compiler will convert the argument for you. Unless you have some additional requirement that you haven't mentioned you could make it even simpler:

```
mySerial->putChar(255);
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I over looked that.  Your answer worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
unsigned int x = 255;
myserial->putChar( static_cast<char>(x) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `s.c_str()` returns a C-string. In this case the string only contains a single characters, but that is not the same as a character variable! A C-string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated with the null character, '\0'. What you are trying to pass to `putChar` is a pointer to the first character of this array.

As suggested by several other posters, you need to use a cast: `putChar( static_cast<char>(x) )`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code didn't work because because `std::to_string(255)` will give you : `std::string("255")` so with your `c_str` conversion, your code is the same as: `myserial->putChar(50);`.

Answer given by Naschkatze is certainly a better approach.